# Laravel 5.5 UploadRequest not working? No errors

Tags: laravel, file-upload, request

I have a form where I can upload multiple files. I created an UploadRequest to validate the files but on submit nothing happens and no errors are being thrown. I have no idea why it is not working or why it is behaving like this.

My form:

```
<?php echo Form::open(['url' => 'upload', 'files' => true]) ?>
                <?php echo Form::token(); ?> 

                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    @foreach($data['damageTypes'] as $damageType)
                        <label class="btn btn-primary">
                            <?php 
                                echo Form::radio('damageType', $damageType->id); 
                                echo $damageType->name_nl;
                            ?>
                        </label>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <?php echo Form::file('photos[]', ['multiple']); ?>

                <?php echo Form::submit('Upload files', $attributes = ['class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block']); ?>

            <?php echo Form::close() ?>

            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
```

My routes:

```
Route::post('upload', 'DamagePointController@uploadSubmit');
```

My controller and uploadsubmit action

```
    /**
     * Handles the upload of the images.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function uploadSubmit(UploadRequest $request)
    {
        //
    }
```

Yes I do `use App\Http\Requests\UploadRequest;`

### EDIT remove name rule

My UploadRequest

```
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $photos = count($this->input('photos'));
        foreach(range(0, $photos) as $index) {
            $rules['photos.' . $index] = 'image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png|max:2000';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

In theorie this should show an error message when uploading an image bigger than 2000kilobytes but nothing happens I get redirected to the homepage.

Comment: I see no name="name" in any input field?

Comment: @Option I use laravelcollective check it out https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html the first parameter is always the name attribute of your html element

Comment: Okay but still where is `Form::text('name')` ?

Comment: You're looking for a field that has no `name` therefore why would it throw a required error?

Comment: @Option Woops you're right that rule is unnecessary I deleted it but I still get no error when uploading a large image

Comment: photo's rule should be within $rules = [ ] the code below shouldn't be in there, it should be in the controller (apart from the actual rules)

Comment: so it would be:  `return [  'photos' => 'rules' ];`

Comment: @Option You can create requests to keep your controllers clean so why not use them? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#creating-form-requests

Comment: To keep them clean yes instead of things like `if(empty($var) { // do this } `

Comment: So I move everything from my UploadRequest to my controller method and simply not use the UploadRequest?

Comment: I didn't say that.. Your rules go into the request. Read above

Comment: @Option I don't understand I am sorry. I will figure it out someway thanks anyways